# Struggling to create this block diagram in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

My task is to create the Simulink block diagram in the picture. Please bare in mind that English isn't my native language. As far as I've figured it out, it has something to do with a heaviside function, but I have no idea how to implement that into a block diagram. I'm quite new to Matlab and Simulink.
[image]

This is as far as I've managed to get :
[image]

Comment: @Adriaan thank you for editing this post

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to do this, depending on how "hard coded" the constants and the time of the step need to be.

For the specific values you've given, simply use a [Product](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/product.html) block and a [Step](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html) block, with the initial value, final value, and step time changed appropriately.

Comment: Why would I use a product block instead of a gain block? I'm getting an error for each of my identical functions, both are syntax errors http://prntscr.com/9lih3n (picture). I'm unable to set the parameters of each step block correctly, because my conditions range to +Inf and -Inf and the step block parameter (Final value parameter) only supports finite values http://prntscr.com/9lihsh .

Comment: The initial value is 5, and the final value is 2.